# Bug with UITableViewCell ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on an iOS project .I created an UITableView to display a list of drones . Everything works fine but I noticed that there is a bug when I click on the cell to display the details of the drone .  As u can see in the images below.

**When the tableView get loded**

[image]

**When clicked on cell**

[image]

and this my code when I select a cell :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *_storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *_storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:_storyboardName bundle: nil];
    DroneDetailsViewController *detailsVC = [_storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DroneDetailsViewController"];
    detailsVC.droneObj = [drones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsVC animated:YES];
    [detailsVC.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
```

This my code for cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"drone";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    DroneObject *droneObjDisplay = nil;
    droneObjDisplay = [drones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:droneObjDisplay.modelMSide options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
    [self initCellWithComponents:cell :data :droneObjDisplay.modelName :droneObjDisplay.modelNumber];
    return cell;
}
```

and this the initCelWithComponents :

```
- (void)initCellWithComponents :(UITableViewCell *)cell :(NSData *)dataImage :(NSString *)title :(NSString *)subTitle {

    UIView *viewCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(VIEW_MARGIN, VIEW_MARGIN, widthtScreen-20, VIEW_IMAGE_HEIGHT)];
    viewCell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:NSLocalizedString(@"border_color", nil)].CGColor;
    viewCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    viewCell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(VIEW_MARGIN,VIEW_MARGIN, VIEW_IMAGE_HEIGHT-(2*VIEW_MARGIN),VIEW_IMAGE_HEIGHT-(2*VIEW_MARGIN))];
    image.image=[UIImage imageWithData:dataImage];
    [viewCell addSubview:image];

    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(image.frame.size.width+2*VIEW_MARGIN, VIEW_MARGIN, viewCell.frame.size.width-(VIEW_IMAGE_HEIGHT-(4*VIEW_MARGIN)), 21)];
    titleLabel.text = title;
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
    [viewCell addSubview:titleLabel];

    UILabel *subTitleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(image.frame.size.width+2*VIEW_MARGIN, 3*VIEW_MARGIN, viewCell.frame.size.width-(VIEW_IMAGE_HEIGHT-(4*VIEW_MARGIN)), 21)];
    subTitleLabel.text = subTitle;
    subTitleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [subTitleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
    [viewCell addSubview:subTitleLabel];

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:NSLocalizedString(@"gray_background", nil)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:viewCell];
}
```

any ideas how to fix that ?!

Comment: Try to Comment didSelectRowAtIndexPath Code & then Select Cell. Update me what will happen.

Comment: aren't you able to navigate to detailVC?

Comment: @SharmaVishal I commented it, when I select a cell there is no bug it's ok but of course it didn't navigate to detailVC

Comment: @Lion yes I can navigate to detailVC and it shows the details of the real cell not the bug one

Comment: This is because, you are reusing UITableViewCell, and in cellForRowAtIndexPath you are creating some controls like UILabel. can you show your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: This could be a work around, you can give it a try - //Disable cell selection
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; Add this to cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I am not getting you exactly!!  in your screenshots any one is of detailVC?

Comment: @BharatModi ,it works !! but I still need the selection style

Comment: @Lion No My detailVC is not in the screenshots . just the table view with and without the selection style

Comment: You are mixing up things here, you are creating an instance of default tableView cell (subtitleCell) and at the same time adding components to the cell manually too. This would definitely lead you to some creating issues. If you want custom cell then simply design the prototype cell on the storyboard/xib itself  and then just dequeue that cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @BharatModi I see but how to create a custom cell without xib?! in my project I'm always using code to design my components

Comment: Are you using storyboard or xibs?

Comment: I'm using storyboard now but the viewcontrollers are empty I will remove it soon because I'm using the code to create my components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally, after getting your answers guys , I created a Custom Cell a subclass of UITableViewCell and I added all my components there . The main problem was how I will call it without UI (storyboard or xib ) just by code .
So after the creation of the custom cell I added this line to my viewdidload :

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[CustomCellTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCellTableViewCell"];
```

then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath I just added the custom cell :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    DroneObject *droneObjDisplay = nil;
    droneObjDisplay = [drones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *identifier = @"CustomCellTableViewCell";
    CustomCellTableViewCell *cell = (CustomCellTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:droneObjDisplay.modelMSide options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
    cell.image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    cell.titleLabel.text = droneObjDisplay.modelName;
    cell.subTitleLabel.text = droneObjDisplay.modelNumber;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cell's style is `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` and you also adding title and subtitle label manually also.

If you are using cell's style as `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` then you can directly use

```
 cell.textLabel.text = @"your title label's text";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"your detail label's text";
```

If you will add another label then it will creates duplicate!!!!

Comment: but I'm not using the default cell's textLabel . I created a new Label
what I understand is that I need to create a custom cell for that right ?!

Comment: Yeah if you want to add custom objects then you should use custom cell. in that you have to add every component. If you are using `subtitle` then definitely two label will be there!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are initialising UIView and UILabel in method inside cellForRowAtIndexPath and adding them as subview, these controls are being added to your cell each time cell is reloaded. Below code identifies each cell with a unique identifier and loads the cell only if that particular cell is not available in UITableView.
I have written droneObjDisplay.droneId to uniquely identify cell, you can write anything for droneObjDisplay.__ that is unique identifier of your object.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
  DroneObject *droneObjDisplay = nil;
  droneObjDisplay = [drones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"drone_%d", droneObjDisplay.droneId];
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) 
  {  
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithBase64EncodedString:droneObjDisplay.modelMSide options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
   [self initCellWithComponents:cell :data :droneObjDisplay.modelName :droneObjDisplay.modelNumber];
  }
  return cell;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . but the bug is still here when you select a cell 
http://imgur.com/a/v6Bc6

Answer (score 0):

**The TableViewCell could be designed and used by either one of the following ways,**

1. If you are using the storyboard then you can simply design the prototype cell on the TableView on storyboard itself and then giving an identifier to the cell. If you are using this way then add the component on the storyboard only and give tag to each component to access it in the code if you are not subclassing the UITableViewCell, and dequeue the cell as below,

   ```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   UILabel *labelValue = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:10];
   ```
2. Design the TableViewCell on the storyboard as you did in 1 way and then simply create a subclass of UITableViewCell class and set that class as a Custom Class of the cell by selecting the cell on storyboard, this way you can create the outlet of each component in the cell and you do not need to access the component by the tags. Below is the code to dequeue the cell,

   ```
   CellSubClassed *cell = (CellSubClassed*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   cell.labelXYZ.text = arrayDataSource[indexPath.row][@"key"];
   ```
3. This is the old way before storyboard was introduced, Create subclass of UITableView cell and create a xib file with the same name you give to UiTableViewCell subclass, create the outlets of component you want to access. Below is the code to dequeue cell,

   ```
   NSArray *nib;
   static NSString *strNibName = @"CustomCell";

   nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:strNibName owner:self options:nil];

   CustomCell *cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   cell.imageView.image = arrayDataSource[indexPath.row];
   ```
4. The last way is using TableView's default cells, just create the tableView on storyboard/xib and dequeue the cell as below,

   ```
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: cellIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }

   cell.textLabel.text = @"xyz";
   ```

The default tableView cell styles are,

- UITableViewCellStyleDefault
- UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
- UITableViewCellStyleValue1
- UITableViewCellStyleValue2

You can read about more on Apple Developer docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html).

So in your case you are mixing the two ways of dequeuing the cell, if you want to add the component manually as you did and you don't want to design the component on the storyboard or Xib then you just create the subclass of UITableView cell and then create the component in the awakeFromNib method and dequeue the cell as explained in 3 way.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation . So there is no way to design the cell only by code without using storyboard or Xib just by code

Comment: Yes off course , you can design the cell by code only. To do that follow the steps as add the tableView on the storyboard add one cell there and give it an identifier, then dequeue the cell as explained in 1 way in my answer and then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath call your initCellWithComponent method that's it. Do not add any component on the storyboard.

Comment: yes but i meant without adding the table view to the storyboard

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel... :)

Comment: because I'm planing to delete the storyboard later :P

Comment: You could search more on how you can do that then, but IMO designing UI on Storyboard/Xib's are way more easy and less time consuming then doing it manually. Choice is yours... :)

Comment: Yeah I know but still need to do it without UI .Thanks man for the explanation :)